# Does Javascript While Loop check DOM every iteration

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

Will a while loop load the DOM every iteration, or will it loop using the DOM as it was when it started?

e.g.

```
function whileExample(){
    while(a > b){
        $('p').each(function(){
            num++
        });
        return num;
    }
)
```

Will that see a 'p' that has been added since the loop started

Comment: Loops by themselves don't examine the DOM.  If there's some *operation* being conducted in the loop which examines the DOM, then it will examine the DOM.  If there isn't, then it won't.

Comment: The DOM is a datastructure created on page load. It is never regenerated. If you don't specifically manipulate it, nothing will happen to it. Manipulating it does not reload it, it just changes the structure.

Comment: do you have an example you are asking about? it would depend on the code. i.e. if you are selecting dom elements in the loop

Comment: Notice that with the `return` statement inside the `while` loop it will never run more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the DOM methods that gets elements returns a live list that will change if the DOM changes, but jQuery makes a copy of the list when it gets the elements.

When you loop the elements in a jQuery object, you are looping the elements that existed when the jQuery element was created.

The `while` loop creates a new jQuery object each iteration, so that would get the elements that exist at that time, but as you return from within the loop there will only be one iteration.

Note however as there is no code that changes the DOM in your loop, it's not possible for any elements to be added in the DOM during the loops. Javascript is single threaded, so there is no other code that can run while the function is running.

Comment: As a selector is being passed to jQuery inside the loop, it does query the DOM every time. If it was stored in a variable ahead of the loop, the jQuery object would not get updated as you manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one DOM, rooted in the "document" object. It is created on page load. The jQuery-function, and everything else operating on the DOM, will search in the DOM as it is when you call it, so it will find ALL p's in the current document. It will NOT find the ones removed, and it WILL find those added.